# Проблемно и проблематично — в чем разница?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Какая разница между словами "проблемно" и "проблематично" и грамотно ли вообще говорить "проблемно"?
Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наречия образовались от прилагательных:

ПРОБЛЕ́МНЫЙ (книжн.). Заключающий в себе проблему, посвященный исследованию, разрешению какой-нибудь проблемы. Проблемная статья. Проблемный роман."Проблема" в значении "что-то трудно разрешимое" - разговорное, следовательно, нейтрального или книжного наречия от него нет, только разговорное - "трудно разрешимо"

ПРОБЛЕМАТИ́ЧЕСКИЙ (книжн.). Предположительный, только вероятный, неокончательный, остающийся еще проблемой. Проблематическое решение вопроса. Проблематический вывод.
|| Сомнительный, маловероятный. Проблематические надежды. Проблематические обещания.«Это наследство было проблематическое, вроде ожидания приезда богатого дяди из Америки.» Гончаров.(ПО Ушакову)  Наречие "Проблематично" - "маловероятно,сомнительно в исполнении, трудно" :Сделать это будет проблематично (трудно).